# How can I read the csv file?

Tags: c++, csv

I have a data, which is seperated by "," and I have 7 lines of that. I am trying to read the data seperated by comma into 2d vector like this:

```
ifstream input;
input.open("wordplate.csv");
vector<vector<string>> data;
string line;
while(getline(input,line)){
    cout<<"A\n";
    stringstream ss(line);
    string value;
    vector<string> record;
    while(getline(ss,value,',')){
        record.push_back(value);
    }
    data.push_back(record);
}

input.close();
```

But for some reason, I am getting only the last line of my csv file. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That works as expected, I get all lines. How do you print it?

Comment: It shows, that my vector data has a size of 1 and data[0] has a size of 109, seems that it pushed back everything into data[0]

Comment: On my machine, it processed 9 records with that data.  I suspect your line endings in your wordplate.csv file are incorrect for your platform.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide real data? I just tested this code in Visual Studio 2015 and it seems to work.

Maybe reading answers here can help you:
[How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c)

Comment: You can have a look at the data

Comment: I meant if you can provide the file which you are reading. Also it seems that line endings are wrong for your OS ( e.g. in windows it should be \r\n and on unix \n)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I print the result:

```
for(auto const& r : data) {
    for(auto const& c : r)
        std::cout << c << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

And it shows that your code reads all csv lines as expected.